# tableview header subview disapearing when reloading sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I would like to create an expandable tableview by tapping on its headers, I have a headerfooterview class called in viewForHeaderInSection to instanciate the header, and it appears nice until I try to reload the section, the subview disappears when the section folds.

here s bit of the code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerClass(CustomHeaderTableViewCell.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "header")
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return data.count

     }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    if section == selectedSection {
         return 0
         } else {
         return data[section].count
         }        
    }

    func expandCollapse(sender: UIButton) {

         self.selectedSection = sender.tag
         tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet( index: sender.tag ), withRowAnimation: .None)

     }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
         let header: CustomHeaderTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("header") as! CustomHeaderTableViewCell
         let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
         button.frame = header.bounds
         button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
         button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
         button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainWitness.expandCollapse), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
         button.tag = section
         header.addSubview(button)

         header.textLabel!.text = "TRENDS"

      return header 
    }
```

Comment: whats in numberofsections in tableview code?

Comment: func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

            return data.count

    }      this part works

Comment: what about heightforheaderinsection?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding a new button to the cell each time you dequeue (reuse) it, you'll have multiple buttons with different tags all on the same cell...

Comment: I should create the button directly in the headerfooterview class ? how to trigger the selected section then and pass the argument to the collapse function in this case ?

Comment: just add a normal view with a button or as told by dev gr create an xib

Comment: @hariszaman could you help me below ? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the header's subview, in this case, your button disappeared is that the height of the headerView is not right in the method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

The height of your headerView is still equal to zero(so is the width of it), so when your code execute `button.frame = header.bounds`,the height will be set to zero, so does the width.So it may not be seen in the screen.

To solve this, you can set the button's frame with some fixed rect like `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 30)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of populating the header from prototype cell, create separate .XIB for header view and populate header view from it. It will work.

Comment: UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIVIew so does it matters then?

Comment: Yes you are right but UITableViewCell is not meant to-be used as a UIView, there are some issue while creating header view out of re-usable cell. I faced same issue and .XIB saved me.

Comment: sorry if I look like a noob, but I don t get it, what do you mean by using a separate .xib ? here i am populating the header with a headerfooterview class ina  prototype cell, I dont get how to do it in any other way

Comment: I have created a new XIB, registered it, but if I don t want to create a button in viewForHeaderInSection, and to use one created directly in the nib, how can I get the actual section header ? This to avoid using tags

Comment: Create a subclass of UIView and make it the owner of the header XIB, connect outlets and actions into that owner class and access the properties using it.

Comment: Use these methods 

- registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:
   - registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:
       - dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier: to work with header view class and XIB.